# SQL Server MERGE command duplicate pk error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This stored procedure often fails if transactions happen simultaneusly, because it violates a pk constraint on duplicate key (field, name). I have been trying, <strike>holdlock,</strike> rowlock and begin/commit transaction, which result in the same error.

I am trying to perform an insert statement and if the record exist with the same key (field, name) update it instead.

Performance is important so i am trying to avoid a temp table solution.

```
MERGE Fielddata AS TARGET
USING (VALUES (@Field, @Name, @Value, @File, @Type))
    AS SOURCE (Field, Name, Value, File, Type)
    ON TARGET.Field = @Field AND TARGET.Name = @Name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET Value = SOURCE.Value,
        File = SOURCE.File,
        Type = SOURCE.Type
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Field, Name, Value, File, Type)
    VALUES (SOURCE.Field, SOURCE.Name, SOURCE.Value, SOURCE.File, SOURCE.Type);
```

EDIT: Testing with serializable/holdlock for 24 hours. After 30 mins: no errors.

EDIT 2: `WITH (SERIALIZABLE)` / `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` solves the duplicate key problem effectively, costing a little bit of performance in our case/scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must increase the level of transaction isolation.
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

> SERIALIZABLE Specifies the following: + Statements cannot read data
>   that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions. No
>   other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current
>   transaction until the current transaction completes. **Other
>   transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in
>   the range of keys read by any statements in the current transaction
>   until the current transaction completes.** Range locks are placed in the
>   range of key values that match the search conditions of each statement
>   executed in a transaction. This blocks other transactions from
>   updating or inserting any rows that would qualify for any of the
>   statements executed by the current transaction. This means that if any
>   of the statements in a transaction are executed a second time, they
>   will read the same set of rows. The range locks are held until the
>   transaction completes. This is the most restrictive of the isolation
>   levels because it locks entire ranges of keys and holds the locks
>   until the transaction completes. Because concurrency is lower, use
>   this option only when necessary. **This option has the same effect as
>   setting HOLDLOCK on all tables in all SELECT statements in a
>   transaction.**

Serializable Implementations

> SQL Server happens to use a locking implementation of the serializable
>   isolation level, where physical locks are acquired and held to the end
>   of the transaction (hence the deprecated table hint HOLDLOCK as a
>   synonym for SERIALIZABLE).
>
> This strategy is not quite enough to provide a technical guarantee of
>   full serializability, because new or changed data could appear in a
>   range of rows previously processed by the transaction. This
>   concurrency phenomenon is known as a phantom, and can result in
>   effects which could not have occurred in any serial schedule.
>
> To ensure protection against the phantom concurrency phenomenon, locks
>   taken by SQL Server at the serializable isolation level may also
>   incorporate key-range locking to prevent new or changed rows from
>   appearing between previously-examined index key values. Range locks
>   are not always acquired under the serializable isolation level; all we
>   can say in general is that SQL Server always acquires sufficient locks
>   to meet the logical requirements of the serializable isolation level.
>   In fact, locking implementations quite often acquire more, and
>   stricter, locks than are really needed to guarantee serializability,
>   but I digress.

https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-serializable-isolation-level

if it is simple: it blocks not only the source but also the range for insertion

Comment: **Must** overstates it. My preference would be to add the `HOLDLOCK` hint to the specific statement.

Comment: HOLDLOCK will give the same result

Comment: So this would effectively be the same?

`MERGE Fielddata WITH HOLDLOCK AS TARGET
USING (VALUES (@Field, @Name, @Value, @File, @Type))
    AS SOURCE (Field, Name, Value, File, Type)
    ON TARGET.Field = @Field AND TARGET.Name = @Name
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET Value = SOURCE.Value,
        File = SOURCE.File,
        Type = SOURCE.Type
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Field, Name, Value, File, Type)
    VALUES (SOURCE.Field, SOURCE.Name, SOURCE.Value, SOURCE.File, SOURCE.Type);`

Comment: "HOLDLOCK is sort of deprecated, and you should use SERILIZABLE instead."

Is this true?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a7536fc4-ed1e-44aa-a16b-d4dc9ca6cd70/what-is-the-difference-between-holdlock-and-updlock-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Comment: @LochNess - It isn't listed as deprecated. You can use `MERGE Fielddata WITH (SERIALIZABLE) AS TARGET USING (VALUES (@Field, @Name, @Value, @File, @Type)) AS SOURCE (Field, Name, Value, File, Type) ON TARGET.Field = @Field AND TARGET.Name = @Name WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Value = SOURCE.Value, File = SOURCE.File, Type = SOURCE.Type WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Field, Name, Value, File, Type) VALUES (SOURCE.Field, SOURCE.Name, SOURCE.Value, SOURCE.File, SOURCE.Type);` if you prefer though as they are equivalent.